# using a user defined function in Rcpp (cppFunction)

Tags: r, rcpp

I have a user defined function in r:

```
blacksch<-function(s_0,k,sigma,r,t)
{
  d1=(log(s_0/k) + (r + (sigma^2)/2)*(t))/(sigma*sqrt(t))
  d2=(log(s_0/k) + (r - (sigma^2)/2)*(t))/(sigma*sqrt(t))

  p=(pnorm(-d2)*k*exp(-r*t))-pnorm(-d1)*s_0
}
```

And I would like to use this function in c++ code that I have written using Rcpp and cppFunction.  I have been through the documentation and examples a few times, but have not been successful.

```
bs_martin<-cppFunction('NumericMatrix compMartin (NumericMatrix st, NumericMatrix dv, double s_0, double k, 
                       double t, double sigma, double r, int steps, int paths, Function blacksch(fun)) {

                       // Ensure RNG scope set
                       RNGScope scope;


        int min_bs_step=0;
        double minbsvalue=0;
        vector<double> u[0]=100.0;
        for(int i=1;i<=paths; i++)
        {
          min_bs_step=0;
          for(int j=1;j<=steps;j++)
          {
            if (dv[i,j]>0 && min_bs_step==0)
            {
                min_bs_step=i;
                minbsvalue=blacksch(s_0,k,sigma,r,t);
            }
            else if (min_bs_step!=0)
            {
                dv[i,j]=1 - minbsvalue;
            }
          }

        }
      return dv;
                       }')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the following:

- Study our documentation and examples. We show how to pass functions around too, even if we do not recommend it (for obvious performance reason, calling R from C++ ain't speedy).
- If you somewhat complex example does not work, try a smaller one. At the end of the day you may just want a tester which receives two numbers and passes those to a supplied function.
- And lastly: You really want `blacksch` in C++ too.  All the statistical functions are available under the same names.

Comment: So I guess making a c++ `blacksch` is a possible (and recommend) solution.

Comment: It should be noted that it is important to cast r function results with `as<type>()` when needed.

Comment: Yes, but you don't need to repeat all the Rcpp documentation here in comments.  Please do study our vignettes, our examples, things like the Rcpp Gallery as well as the countless answers here and on the mailing list.  Make Google your new best friend.

Comment: I'm having a hard time finding anything on including two functions inside `cppFunction()` I get an error like: `error: 'blacksch' was not declared in this scope` when I try to add this function inside the same `cppFunction()`

Comment: Did it occur to you that you may be using the function the wrong way /  using the wrong function?  Did you read the 'Rcpp Attributes' vignettes?

Comment: It did occur to me.  But after reading the Rcpp Attributes I still do not understand.  I am not an expert.  I have not claimed to be an expert.  I am asking an expert for help.  I know for certain I am using the function the wrong way since it is called `cppFunction` not `cppFunctions` and empirically, I have shown what I am attempting does not work.  I'm just a bit stuck on where to go from here.

Comment: In a very short nutshell, you misunderstand what `cppFunction()` is for. Look at `sourceCpp()`, look at creating a package.

Comment: I am on that road right now, and it appears to be working for me.